# In ScalaPb, How to create a case object and case class extending from the same trait?

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, scalapb

All of my case classes and case objects should be in protobuf. Now I need for them to belong to a single trait.

Sadly this is how I have done:

```
message WGCommand {
    oneof sealed_value {
        EnqueueWorkDone enq = 1;
        OpenWorkgroup oWg = 3;
    }
}

message OpenWorkgroup {}

message EnqueueWorkDone {
    required string id = 1;
    required string actorRef = 2;
}
```

This one creates

```scala
final case class OpenWorkgroup(){...}
```

I want my protobuf to produce something like this:

```scala
sealed trait WGCommand
case object OpenWorkgroup extends WGCommand
case class EnqueueWorkDone(id:String, actorRef:String) extends WGCommand
```

Comment: I think that what you are asking is how you can make a message with no fields be a case object and not a case class. This is not currently possible, but came up in the past and it's an enhancement that we can consider (see https://github.com/scalapb/ScalaPB/issues/485) - feel free to leave a note on that issue. In the mean time, you can create your own ADT hierarchy and use custom types to convert to and from them.

Comment: Thanks @thesamet. 

I've resigned myself to using empty messages. I got more case classes than case objects anyway.  

If you could transfer your comment as an answer... I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are asking is how you can make a message with no fields be a case object and not a case class. This is not currently possible, but came up in the past and it's an enhancement that we can consider (see https://github.com/scalapb/ScalaPB/issues/485) - feel free to leave a note on that issue. In the mean time, you can create your own ADT hierarchy and use custom types to convert to and from them.